# count number of times specific data occurs using join function in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am bringing data from two tables 'stay' and 'pet' table using join function. I was wondering how i can count the amount of times 'cat' occurs in the returned data.

```
SELECT pet.petID, pet.species   
from stay   
inner join pet   
on (stay.petID = pet.petID) 



 petID Species
    8   Cat
    8   Cat
    8   Cat
    9   Cat
    11  Cat
    12  Cat
    12  Cat
    14  Cat
    39  Dog
    39  Dog
    40  Dog
    41  Dog
```

Comment: If you add `WHERE species = 'cat'` to the end of your query then the answer will be the same as the number of rows returned.

Comment: Check out the MySQL's count() function

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM stay
INNER JOIN pet
    ON stay.petID = pet.petID
WHERE pet.species = 'Cat'
```

But what would more interesting (and possibly more useful) would be a result set which shows counts for all the animal types, in which you case you can try this:

```
SELECT pet.species,
       COUNT(*) AS petCount
FROM stay
INNER JOIN pet
    ON stay.petID = pet.petID
GROUP BY pet.species
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT pet.petID, count(pet.species) as no_of_species,pet.species
from stay
inner join pet
    on (stay.petID = pet.petID)
group by pet.species

Answer (score 0):

By adding only `WHERE species = 'cat'`

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
from stay
inner join pet
    on (stay.petID = pet.petID)
where pet.species = 'Cat'
```